# Vaught's essentially undecidable set theory

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, incompleteness

Today I was reading [this](http://www.mi.ras.ru/~bekl/Papers/goedel-en.pdf) paper, which includes discussion of essential undecidability of various weak theories. On page 24, I was surprised to find out that Vaught has showed that set theory with the following two axioms is essentially undecidable:

$$\forall x\exists y\neg(y\in x)$$
$$\forall x,y\exists u\forall z(z\in u\Leftrightarrow(z\in x\lor z\in y))$$

I was surprised as I have found in some recent paper (which I can't remember) that [ST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_set_theory) is the simplest known set theory which is essentially undecidable, while (arguably) Vaught's theory is simpler. I wasn't able to track down Vaught's work which would talk of this theory.

On the second thought, this theory seems unlikely to be essentially undecidable, because, first, it vacuously has an empty model, and second, less trivially, a finite model with $\in$ being empty relation seems to satisfy the theory as well, thus giving a decidable extension of the theory.

> Can anyone provide a reference for where Vaught proves essential undecidability of this theory?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Since the result seems to be false, the question arises whether the article I mention on the beginning has a typo. Finding a work of Vaught which the paper appears to be quoting might help clarify that, but again - I couldn't find anything.

Comment: $z\in z \:$ should presumably be replaced with $\: z\in x \;$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Of course. Thank you.

Comment: Empty models are not allowed in usual first-order logic, but any (finite or infinite) model with an empty $\in$ relation would be enough to prove that extending the theory with $\forall x,y(x\notin y)$ produces a consistent theory, which will be trivially decidable.

Comment: Just before the claim in question is a reference "(see [33]--[36])", and reference [33] is indeed a paper by Vaught. It would seem most meaningful if that is supposed to be the one that contains the result.

Comment: Reference [33] links to a review that sounds like it's mostly about arithmetic, but ends with: _"Der Verfasser gibt zum Schluß $R_0$ entsprechende Theorien in der Mengenlehre an und weist auf weitere Probleme hin."_ which sounds vaguely like it _could_ be it.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally switch $\forall$ and $\exists$ in the first axiom (which would yield the empty set axiom)?

Comment: @user76284 I understand the confusion, but I am fairly certain the axiom as written is correct (it is written the same way in the paper). If it was to be the axiom of empty set, it would have finite models (power set of any finite set), so wouldn't be essentially undecidable.

Comment: @Wojowu Right. What about replacing the second axiom by [adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_adjunction)? Unfortunately, I have not been able to access R. L. Vaught's *On a theorem of Cobham concerning undecidable theories*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are just typos. (The axioms as given do not form an essentially undecidable theory, as they have lots of finite models.)

The story on top of p. 24 is clearly meant to refer to the *adjunctive set theory* (AS) with axioms
$$\exists x\:\forall y\:\neg(y\in x),$$

$$\forall x,y\:\exists u\:\forall z\:\bigl(z\in u\leftrightarrow(z\in x\lor z=y)\bigr).$$
Indeed, this theory extended with the axiom of extensionality was introduced and proved essentially undecidable by Szmielew and Tarski, and essential undecidability of the version here without extensionality was shown in Vaught’s paper *On a theorem of Cobham concerning undecidable theories* (Proc. Logic, Methodology and Philosophy of Science 1960, pp. 14–25). The theory AS is mutually interpretable with Robinson’s arithmetic Q.

An even weaker essentially undecidable theory, nowadays often called *Vaught’s set theory* (VS), was introduced in Vaught’s paper *Axiomatizability by a schema* (JSL 32 (1967), pp. 473–479). Its axioms consist of the schema
$$\forall x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}\:\exists u\:\forall z\:\Bigl(z\in u\leftrightarrow\bigvee_{i<n}z=x_i\Bigr)$$
for all $n\ge0$. The theory VS interprets Robinson’s theory R; like R, and unlike AS or Q, it is not finitely axiomatizable. There is a mention of VS on p. 26 of Beklemishev’s paper (again, with a typo: the axioms need to be stated for $n\ge0$, not just $n\ge1$, i.e., including the axiom of the empty set).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have realized the theory from the cited papers has finite models, especially after I made the comment above about it being the case for empty set + the messed up adjunction axiom. Thank you for the references as well!

Comment: Is VS the weakest known essentially undecidable theory?

Comment: @user76284 Certainly not. E.g., Robinson’s R is strictly weaker (wrt computable interpretations) than VS. Theories like REP_U or REP_{PRF} from my paper “Recursive functions and existentially closed structures” are strictly weaker than R. For even weaker essentially undecidable theories, fix any recursively inseparable pair of r.e. sets $A,B\subseteq\omega$, and take the theory with constants $\{c_n:n\in\omega\}$, a unary predicate $P$, and axioms $P(c_n)$ for $n\in A$ and $\neg P(c_n)$ for $n\in B$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Sorry, I mean over a language with only a binary relation (like $\in$).

Comment: Same answer. You can encode any r.e. theory by a theory whose language only has a binary relation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a finitely axiomatizable such theory that is weaker than VS (or AS for that matter)?

Comment: No finitely axiomatizable theory interpretable in VS is essentially undecidable, as all finite fragments of VS have decidable completions. I can’t recall any *natural* finitely axiomatized ess. undec. theory weaker than AS/Q, but such theories exist, as no consistent fin. ax. ess. und. theory is minimal  (wrt interpretation) with this property, see https://mathoverflow.net/a/359268 and the comments below.